# Pinch/spread touch zoom — How do I avoid creating a “zoom trap”?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, touch

I have a desktop web app (skyviewcafe.com) that I’m trying to make more mobile-friendly. As one step in that process, I’ve taken a star chart and made it touch-draggable, and also made a view of the orbits of the planets both draggable and zoomable with touch gestures.

But here’s an interesting problem that I imagine must have happened to others before: It’s possible to use the default panning and zooming behavior of a mobile web browser to move my web page around until the only thing in view is a component that itself takes over touch gestures using `preventDefault`.

Once this happens, it’s impossible to zoom back out and bring the whole web page back into view. All pinch/spread zooming is sucked in by my component. For lack of a better term, I’m calling this a “zoom trap”. I’ve tried to search online for any discussion of this problem, but can’t find the right words to match anything.

I came up with an ad hoc solution that’s currently deployed at http://test.skyviewcafe.com. If I’m in a “zoom trap” I can touch the screen with three fingers and a translucent gray panel comes up to block touch gestures from reaching my touch-responsive canvas. Normal default web browser pan and zoom then becomes possible again, and the user can zoom back out. After that, touching with three fingers again clears the gray panel out of the way.

While this solves the problem in a way, it’s not a standard well-known gesture, and it would be hard to provide enough on-screen prompting to make necessary gesture clear.

Ideally I’d like to be able to respond to a standard gesture like a double-tap by zooming out the web page, but as far as I can tell, other than the initial zoom factor when a web page loads, web browser zooming isn’t something a web app can control dynamically.

Has anyone else run into this problem? Are there standard touch gestures for dealing with this? Are there ways in JavaScript that I haven’t discovered yet to dynamically control mobile web browser zooming?